# Как заставить один элемент хтмл страницы исчезнуть и появиться другой по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Итак, друзья, возникла у меня проблема... Казалось бы все просто, но что-то у меня не сходится, так что нужна ваша помощь.
В общем: есть две таблицы. Таблица 1 по умолчанию рисуется на странице ХТМЛ, а Таблица 2 по умолчанию невидима (в идеале должна вообще не отрисовываться). В таблице 1 есть кнопка "Таб1" при нажатии на которую, по задумке Таблица 1 должна исчезать и появляться Таблица 2... Вот только, сколько я не игрался со свойствами "display" и "visibilyty" - ничего у меня не получилось. Я даже тег "тайбл" заменил на "див", подумав, что "visibilyty" для таблицы просто не работает.
Вот что у меня в итоге получилось:
ХТМЛ:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, instant-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/battle.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/table.css">
    <title>Build Castle</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/menu.js"></script>
    <script>if((self.parent&&!(self.parent===self))&&(self.parent.frames.length!=0)){self.parent.location=document.location}</script>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="tab1" class="castle">
    <row>
      <cell> 1</cell><cell> 2</cell><cell>3 </cell><cell>4 </cell><cell>5 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>6 </cell><cell> 7</cell><cell> 8</cell><cell> 9</cell><cell>10 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>11 </cell><cell>12 </cell><cell>13 </cell><cell>14 </cell><cell>15 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>16 </cell><cell>17 </cell><cell>17 </cell><cell>17 </cell><cell>20 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>21 </cell><cell>22 </cell><cell><button id="but1" onclick="enter_donjon()">Ener to donjon?</button> </cell><cell>24 </cell><cell>25 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell> 26</cell><cell>27 </cell><cell>28 </cell><cell>29 </cell><cell>30 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell> 31</cell><cell><button>Ener to castle?</button> </cell><cell>33 </cell><cell>34 </cell><cell>35 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell> 36</cell><cell>37 </cell><cell>38 </cell><cell>39 </cell><cell>40 </cell>
    </row>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="donjon">
    <row>
      <cell> 1</cell><cell> 2</cell><cell>3 </cell><cell>4 </cell><cell>5 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>6 </cell><cell> 7</cell><cell> 8</cell><cell> 9</cell><cell>10 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>11 </cell><cell>12 </cell><cell>13 </cell><cell>14 </cell><cell>15 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>16 </cell><cell>17 </cell><cell>17 </cell><cell>17 </cell><cell>20 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>21 </cell><cell>22 </cell><cell><button id="but2" onclick="enter_castle">Ener to donjon?</button> </cell><cell>24 </cell><cell>25 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell> 26</cell><cell>27 </cell><cell>28 </cell><cell>29 </cell><cell>30 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell> 31</cell><cell><button>Ener to castle?</button> </cell><cell>33 </cell><cell>34 </cell><cell>35 </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell> 36</cell><cell>37 </cell><cell>38 </cell><cell>39 </cell><cell>40 </cell>
    </row>
  </div>
</body>
```

Код яваскрипт:
Пробовал через Id элемента обращаться:

```
function enter_donjon() {
  document.getElementById('tab1').hidden = true;
  document.getElementById('tab2').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

И через класс элемента:

```
function enter_donjon() {
  document.getElementByClass('castle').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.getElementByClass('donjon').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Настройки CSS:

```
.castle {
  display: table;
  background: url(../image/Castle.jpg) 100% 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  visibility: visible;
}

.donjon {
  display: table;
  background: url(../image/Trone.jpg) 100% 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  visibility: hidden;
}

cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  color:red;
}

row {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Еще CSS пробовал через Id элемента задавать:

```
div#tab1 {
  display: table;
  background: url(../image/Castle.jpg) 100% 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  visibility: visible;
}

div#tab2 {
  display: table;
  background: url(../image/Trone.jpg) 100% 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  visibility: hidden;
}

cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  color:red;
}

row {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Итак, вопрос: что я делаю не так?

Comment: `<button id="but1" onclick="enter_donjon()">Ener to donjon?</button>`

Comment: TemirStack, спасибо, все заработало.